# C++: operator<< Overloads not working

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Because I am working on a mikrocontroller, where I don't have std::cout available, I want to define several `operator<<()` functions for my print class.

Because I have several print-backend-classes (one for each output channel e.g. uart, wireless, aso.), I wanted to define my `operator<<()` functions as templates.

But if I want to call this overloads, they don't work. I get compiler errors like

```
no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘print_t’ and ‘gsl::basic_string_span<const char, -1>’)
```

I have the following Example:

```
#include <gsl/string_span>

template <typename T=char, std::size_t N>
constexpr gsl::cstring_span<> gen_cstring_span(const char (&a)[N]) noexcept {
    return gsl::cstring_span<>(a, N);
}

class print_t {
    public:
    inline void append(const gsl::cstring_span<> buf) noexcept {
        for(auto c : buf) {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
};

print_t p;

class prefix_t {
    public:
    static constexpr char prefix[] = "Prefix: ";

    template<typename T>
    print_t& operator<<(T&& arg) noexcept {
        fprintf(stderr, "fwd, ");
        p.append(prefix);
        p << std::forward<T>(arg);
        return p;
    }
};

template<typename T>
using span_append_function_exists = std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(static_cast<void(T::*)(const gsl::cstring_span<>)noexcept>(&T::append))>;

template<typename stream_t, std::enable_if_t<
        span_append_function_exists<stream_t>::value, bool>>
stream_t& operator<<(stream_t& sb, const gsl::cstring_span<> str) noexcept {
    sb.append(str);
    fprintf(stderr, "cstring_span, ");
    return sb;
}

template<typename stream_t, typename T=char, std::size_t N>
stream_t& operator<<(stream_t& sb, const char (&str)[N]) noexcept {
    fprintf(stderr, "string_literal, ");
    auto s = gen_cstring_span(str);
    return sb << s;
}

template<typename stream_t>
stream_t& operator<<(stream_t& sb, const bool flag) noexcept {
    fprintf(stderr, "bool, ");
    if(flag) {
        return sb << gen_cstring_span("true");
    } else {
        return sb << gen_cstring_span("false");
    }
}

prefix_t pre;


int main() {
    gsl::cstring_span<> span{gen_cstring_span("span")};

    p << span << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    p << "string-literal" << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    p << true << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");

    pre << span << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    pre << "string-literal" << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    pre << true << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
```

This example should be C++17 (and was designed to work on a classic pc, but it should be ported to the MC.) and in this example, the print-backend-class would be `print_t`.

And each of the `operator<<()` functions has a template-parameter `stream_t`, which should become in this example the backend-class `print_t`.

I have worked with `std::enable_if<>`, to enable the `sream_t` param only on classes where the append() function is defined, but I did not succeed well.

Additionally, If I apply the operator on class `prefix_t`, it should print everything to the backend and additionally add a prefix-value before the output.

The expected STDOUT:

```
span
string-literal
true
Prefix: span
Prefix: string-literal
Prefix: true
```

The expected STDERR:

```
cstring_span, 
string_literal, cstring_span, 
bool, cstring_span, 
fwd, cstring_span, 
fwd, string_literal, cstring_span, 
fwd, bool, cstring_span,
```

And a short part of the compiler errors:

```
tmp3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp3.cpp:65:7: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘print_t’ and ‘gsl::cstring_span<> {aka gsl::basic_string_span<const char, -1>}’)
     p << span << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
     ~~^~~~~~~
tmp3.cpp:36:11: note: candidate: template<class stream_t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype (static_cast<void (T::*)(gsl::basic_string_span<const char, -1>) noexcept>(& T:: append))>::value, bool>::type <anonymous> > stream_t& operator<<(stream_t&, gsl::cstring_span<>)
 stream_t& operator<<(stream_t& sb, const gsl::cstring_span<> str) noexcept {
           ^~~~~~~~
tmp3.cpp:36:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tmp3.cpp:65:10: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
     p << span << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
          ^~~~
tmp3.cpp:43:11: note: candidate: template<class stream_t, class T, long unsigned int N> stream_t& operator<<(stream_t&, const char (&)[N])
 stream_t& operator<<(stream_t& sb, const char (&str)[N]) noexcept {
           ^~~~~~~~
tmp3.cpp:43:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tmp3.cpp:65:10: note:   mismatched types ‘const char [N]’ and ‘gsl::cstring_span<> {aka gsl::basic_string_span<const char, -1>}’
     p << span << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
          ^~~~
tmp3.cpp:50:11: note: candidate: template<class stream_t> stream_t& operator<<(stream_t&, bool)
 stream_t& operator<<(stream_t& sb, const bool flag) noexcept {
           ^~~~~~~~
tmp3.cpp:50:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tmp3.cpp:65:10: note:   cannot convert ‘span’ (type ‘gsl::cstring_span<> {aka gsl::basic_string_span<const char, -1>}’) to type ‘bool’
     p << span << "\n";fprintf(stderr, "\n");
```

I am using C++17 with g++7.3.

Comment: Clearly, your first `<<`-operator isn't considered viable by your compiler. That's the only one that takes `gsl::cstring_span<>` arguments. The other two variants don't take `gsl::cstring_span<>` arguments so to use one of those, you have to convert to the corresponding type.

Comment: Your `enable_if_t` parameter should have a default argument.